# No value for uid error in JSON response on Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, sqlite

Need some help on how to access 'Json' object 's that  have a nested object? when trying to read the json object on android studio, this error shows up. Already check the structure of the json object for "uid", but still cannot be read. as the error show "No value for uid".

> 05-01 07:42:16.478 11667-11667/com.hybridelements.medicalmanagement W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for uid

So how to get the right nested object inside the object?

This is my json object that capture in android.  :Json Objects:

```
{
  "0": {
    "patientName": "Hitamtestxvnccn",
    "uid": "5901e0fa972f63.91105545",
    "patient": {
      "careGiver": "www@www.com",
      "patientName": "Hitamtestxvnccn",
      "dob": "1945-03-21",
      "created_at": "2017-04-27 20:15:54",
      "updated_at": null
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "patientName": "qasdfghjm",
    "uid": "5901edbf5ebcc2.67869395",
    "patient": {
      "careGiver": "www@www.com",
      "patientName": "qasdfghjm",
      "dob": "1945-03-21",
      "created_at": "2017-04-27 21:10:23",
      "updated_at": null
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "patientName": "patientfromandroid",
    "uid": "590433fa0905a0.83840447",
    "patient": {
      "careGiver": "www@www.com",
      "patientName": "patientfromandroid",
      "dob": "1990-06-11",
      "created_at": "2017-04-29 14:34:34",
      "updated_at": null
    }
  },
  "3": {
    "patientName": "FromAndroid",
    "uid": "59043666cb9026.76887135",
    "patient": {
      "careGiver": "www@www.com",
      "patientName": "FromAndroid",
      "dob": "1995-06-11",
      "created_at": "2017-04-29 14:44:54",
      "updated_at": null
    }
  },
  "4": {
    "patientName": "wwwPatientAndroid",
    "uid": "590438b2eb99e7.18283913",
    "patient": {
      "careGiver": "www@www.com",
      "patientName": "wwwPatientAndroid",
      "dob": "1995-06-11",
      "created_at": "2017-04-29 14:54:42",
      "updated_at": null
    }
  },
  "error": false
}
```

Code use to read the json object. :MainActivity.java:

```
try {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

        // Check for error node in json
        if (!error) {
            // Patient's details successfully captured

            // Now store the patients in SQLite
            for(int i = 0; i < jObj.length(); i++){
                String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("id");
                String careGiver = user.getString("careGiver");
                String patientName = user.getString("patientName");
                String patientDOB = user.getString("dob");
                String created_at = user.getString("created_at");
                String updated_at = user.getString("updated_at");

                // Inserting row in users table
                db.addPatient(careGiver, patientName, uid, patientDOB, created_at, updated_at);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well a lot of code dumped. But where does the error come from? What is missing? If you have a JSON exception then it will not have to do much with a database. Nor with inserting. So where do you get that exception exactly?

Comment: @greenapps from the android studio log, from this particular line ' String uid = jObj.getString("uid");' in my MainActivity.java .

Comment: The error is clear, there is no `uid` in your json object. Print your json object to see what's actually in it.

Comment: Well then you know what goes wrong. And where. You could have told that before. Now find out why a uid is missing.

Comment: As you can see that i have provided my json object after the response inside the android studio, i already check multiple times and make sure the uid is inside the json object, but still the error occurs.

Comment: Check out this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) it is about retrieving data from MySQL to Android. Search from class called LoadAllProducts in AllProductsActivity.

Comment: At least you are to early with that statement as that json object contains objects itself. You should place it after you determined object user i think. It looks to me that you are not able to determine even one json parameter. You should have told that. Again your problem has noting to do with inserting in a database but only with parsing the json response text.

Comment: That's true my friend. but i finally able to solve my problem with some hint or suggestion form you guys. i've already posted my answer to this problem. Really appreciate all your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solve my problem over a cup of coffee. So here is my solution. After make a few changes from my previous for loop in `MainActivity.java`, i change the number of loop from  `for(int i = 0; i < jObj.length(); i++)` to `for(int i = 0; i < jObj.length()-1; i++)` ( -1 from the jObj.length()). Then i add a few line as follows

`String id = jObj.getString("uid);` to `String id = jObj.getString(Integer.toString(i));`

add new line like

`JSONObject idd = jObj.getJSONObject(Integer.toString(i));`

`String uid = idd.getString("uid");`

and add this for the for loop

`JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject(Integer.toString(i)).getJSONObject("patient");`

And finally i managed to insert all data from my Json Object into the databases(Sqlite).

Here is the full code for the for loop method.

```
for(int i = 0; i < jObj.length()-1; i++){
                        String id = jObj.getString(Integer.toString(i));

                        JSONObject idd = jObj.getJSONObject(Integer.toString(i));
                        String uid = idd.getString("uid");


                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject(Integer.toString(i)).getJSONObject("patient");
                        String careGiver = user.getString("careGiver");
                        String patientName = user.getString("patientName");

                        String patientDOB = user.getString("dob");
                        String created_at = user.getString("created_at");
                        String updated_at = user.getString("updated_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addPatient(careGiver, patientName, uid, patientDOB, created_at, updated_at);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your "jObj" object which is mainly your whole Json response doesn't have "uid" as a key. This key is inside your JSON objects names "1","2" etc.

[image: See your json response doesn't have "uid" like "error" key]

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation..really appreciate it. btw i just solved my own problem while having a cup of coffee.